# Cmake - I have to run cmake --build . twice for a binary to be build

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a problem with Conan and Cmake:

With conan i'm downloading my libraries and i want to compile with Cmake, here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(BABEL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(PROJECT_NAME BABEL)

set(SOURCES qt/main.cpp)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)

conan_basic_setup(KEEP_RPATHS)

if (APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../lib")
endif (APPLE)

file(WRITE ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/qt.conf [Paths]\nPrefix=${CONAN_QT_ROOT})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

find_package(portaudio REQUIRED)
find_package(opus REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Network Core Gui REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CONAN_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opus)

if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio_x64)
else()
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio)
endif()
```

if I write this command :

```
mkdir build && cd build && conan install .. && cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" && cmake --build.
```

I'll have to write cmake --build . a second time for the binary to be built, any idea of what i did wrong here ?

edit Here is the result of the build :

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/laurent/Documents/Delivery/Tek3/CPP/B-CPP-500-LYN-5-1-babel-kevin.melinon/build
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /Users/laurent/Documents/Delivery/Tek3/CPP/B-CPP-500-LYN-5-1-babel-kevin.melinon/build
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findportaudio.cmake
-- Library portaudio found /Users/laurent/.conan/data/portaudio/19.7.0/bincrafters/stable/package/22e8f592c814313580425adf77089996d9853e39/lib/libportaudio.dylib
-- Found: /Users/laurent/.conan/data/portaudio/19.7.0/bincrafters/stable/package/22e8f592c814313580425adf77089996d9853e39/lib/libportaudio.dylib
-- Conan: Using autogenerated FindOpus.cmake
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (Opus) does
  not match the name of the calling package (opus).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/Findopus.cmake:81 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I can't put the full result.

Comment: You probably have to show the text output produced for us to understand the build issue.

Comment: how does that output end though? we need to see the final output of the `cmake --build .` command.

Comment: here is the end of the first cmake --build . : `-- Found: /Users/laurent/.conan/data/qt/5.15.2/_/_/package/38dca09af9f0c48f937a38c8ac5f1d5d03a37a22/lib/libQt5Network_debug.dylib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/laurent/Documents/Delivery/Tek3/CPP/B-CPP-500-LYN-5-1-babel-kevin.melinon/build` and here is the second : `[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BABEL.dir/qt/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/BABEL
[100%] Built target BABEL`

Comment: i mean, it built. It is somewhere.

Comment: It must be built yeah, but, all the cache files and etc are built from the first one, but the `[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BABEL.dir/qt/main.cpp.o [100%] Linking CXX executable bin/BABEL [100%] Built target BABEL` only appears when typing the second cmake --build . followed by the apparition of the binary

Comment: The message `-- Build files have been written to: ...` terminates the configuration process. (Initiated by `cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"`). Call to `cmake --build .` should definitely produce more messages. If this is not your case, then `cmake --build.` is simply **not executed**. Instead of putting all commands into a &&-separated sequence, try to execute them manually, one by one. And check, that the first `cmake --build.` gives the usual output about building somthing.

Comment: I'll check, sadly the project asks to run all of it in one command, but at least we'll learn a bit more of it. Edit: It was actually it, with the full command, cmake --build . was not running, thanks for your help all, i'm going to find why it happens but it's at least we know how to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there is a bug when writing all the command in one, typing them one by one solved the problem.